# Would a 'function_not_found_handle ()' loadable bash builtin be possible?

Tags: bash, shell

I wrote a function to handle unknown commands in bash
via `command_not_found_handle ()`.
My intention is to source scripts on demand and access
its functions inside the handler.
But unfortunately the sourced functions run in a subshell so
variables are lost after return/exit.

Finally I did it with some signal/trap/fifo mechanism to command_not_found_handle's parent shell to achieve my goal, but its everything but elegant.

Now I am wondering if `function_not_found_handle` loadable builtin could be implemented.
The builtin should be called if `command_not_found_handle ()` fails.

For the time being I found a [great article by Ed Schaefer](http://www.drdobbs.com/shell-corner-bash-dynamically-loadable-b/199102950) about this subject, but it seems to be an entrance point.

Is anyone experienced with dynamically loadable builtin bash commands?
Who could point me to useful information?

I hope to come up with some results soon to concretize my question.

Thank you!

Comment: you can find loadable builtin examples in bash source code's `examples/loadables` dir.